# How to update a flask template variable without using AJAX

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask template, and I need to update a variable put in the template(`render_template('file.html', somevar='hello'`). When `somevar` is changed, I want it to change in the template as well. How would you go around doing this?

main.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask('app')
somevar = 'somestring'
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
  return render_template('index.html', somevar=somevar)

@app.route('/alter')
def alter():
  global somevar
  somevar = 'anotherstring'
  return 'completed'

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{ somevar }}
</body>
</html>
```

When the `/alter` endpoint is hit, I want index.html to update without reloading it.
I have already tried AJAX, I'm wondering if there is any way to do it without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible without Ajax.

But do you can also return the updated HTML:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask('app')
somevar = 'somestring'
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
  return render_template('index.html', somevar=somevar)

@app.route('/alter')
def alter():
  global somevar
  somevar = 'anotherstring'
  return render_template('index.html', somevar=somevar)

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```